# Can anyone please check/verify this proof?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, analytic-number-theory

Prove that $ 3\mid \sigma_{1}(3k+2) $ for each positive integer $ k $.

Here's my proof:

Let $3k+2=p_{1}^{k_{1}}p_{2}^{k_{2}}\dotsb p_{s}^{k_{s}}.$
Then $3\equiv 0\pmod {3}$ and $3k+2\equiv 2\pmod {3}.$
Thus $p_{i}^{k_{i}}\not\equiv 0\pmod {3} $ for $ i=1, 2, ..., s.$
Suppose all $p_{i}^{k_{i}}\equiv 1\pmod {3}.$
Then $ p_{1}^{k_{1}}p_{2}^{k_{2}}\dotsb p_{s}^{k_{s}}\equiv 1\pmod {3} $.
Since $ p_{1}^{k_{1}}p_{2}^{k_{2}}\dotsb p_{s}^{k_{s}}\equiv 2\pmod {3} $,
it follows that there exists one $p_{i}$ satisfying $ p_{i}^{k_{i}}\equiv 2\pmod {3} $.
This means $ p_{i}\equiv 2\pmod {3} $.
Observe that $ p_{i}^{2}\equiv 4\equiv 1\pmod {3} $ and $ p_{i}^{3}\equiv 8\equiv 2\pmod {3} $.
If $ p_{i}^{r}\equiv 2\pmod {3} $, then $r$ must be odd.
This  implies $ p_{i}^{k_{i}}\equiv 2\pmod {3} $ where $k_{i}$ is odd.
Now we have $ \sigma_{1}(p_{i}^{k_{i}})=p_{i}^{k_{i}}+p_{i}^{k_{i}-1}+\dotsb +p_{i}+1 $
$\equiv [2+1+\dotsb +2+1]\pmod {3}$
$\equiv 0\pmod {3}$,
because $ p_{i}^{r}\equiv 2\pmod {3} $ if $r$ is odd and $ p_{i}^{r}\equiv 1\pmod {3} $ if $r$ is even.
Thus
\begin{align*}
\ 3\mid \sigma_{1}(p_{i}^{k_{i}})\implies 3\mid [\sigma_{1}(p_{1}^{k_{1}})\dotsb \sigma_{1}(p_{i}^{k_{i}})\dotsb \sigma_{1}(p_{s}^{k_{s}})]\\
\implies \sigma_{1}(p_{1}^{k_{1}}p_{2}^{k_{2}}\dotsb p_{s}^{k_{s}})\\
\end{align*}
where $\sigma_{1}$ is multiplicative.
Therefore, $ 3\mid \sigma_{1}(3k+2) $ for each positive integer $k$.

Above is my proof for this question/problem. Can anyone please take a look at this and check/verify to see if it's correct?

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $k_i$ is odd for $every$ $p_i$ such that $p_i\equiv 2 \pmod 3.$ But there must exist at least one $p_i\equiv 2\pmod 3$ with $k_i$ odd, otherwise the product could not be $3k+2.$

Answer (score 1):

Comment: For particular cases we may  say :

1-If $3k+2$ is prime then $\sigma=3k+2+1=3(k+1)\Rightarrow 3|\sigma( 3k+2)$

2- We rewrite $3k+2$ as:

$3k+2=3k+3-1=3m-1$

Suppose we can write:

$3m-1=(3t-1)^{2n+1} $

The sum of divisors will be:

$\sigma=\frac{[(3t-1)^{2n+2}=3S+1]-1}{(3t-1)-1}=3 x\Rightarrow 3|\sigma(3k+2)$